# generate all possibilities while swapping elements between two lists in scala

Tags: scala, list, recursion, generator, yield

Looking for an elegant solution: I have two lists and want to create all possible results when swapping elements (lists with same size, swap only in same position)

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = List(4,5,6)
...
//result
List(
    (List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6)),
    (List(1,2,6), List(4,5,3)),
    (List(1,5,3), List(4,2,6)),
    (List(1,5,6), List(4,2,3)),
    (List(4,2,3), List(1,5,6)),
    (List(4,2,6), List(1,5,3)),
    (List(4,5,3), List(1,2,6)),
    (List(4,5,6), List(1,2,3))
)
```

I could do it with loops, but i want to use immutable lists and do not understand how to do it with generator function stuff (`yield`). Any idea?

Comment: What about `(List(4,5,3), List(1,2,6))`?

Comment: @FilippoVitale yes thx, edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be a combination of `.subsets` and `.updated`:

```
scala> Set(0,1,2).subsets
Set()
Set(0)
Set(1)
Set(2)
Set(0, 1)
Set(0, 2)
Set(1, 2)
Set(0, 1, 2)

scala> (a.updated(0,b(0)), b.updated(0,a(0)))
(List(4, 2, 3),List(1, 5, 6))
```

Therefore:

```
scala> (0 to a.length - 1).toSet.subsets
  .map(_.foldLeft((a,b)){ 
    case (acc, i) => (acc._1.updated(i,b(i)), acc._2.updated(i,a(i)))})
(List(1, 2, 3),List(4, 5, 6))
(List(4, 2, 3),List(1, 5, 6))
(List(1, 5, 3),List(4, 2, 6))
(List(1, 2, 6),List(4, 5, 3))
(List(4, 5, 3),List(1, 2, 6))
(List(4, 2, 6),List(1, 5, 3))
(List(1, 5, 6),List(4, 2, 3))
(List(4, 5, 6),List(1, 2, 3))
```

1. Once generated the `subsets` of the indices to swap
2. We can `fold` using as zero/seed a tuple with the input lists
3. At every index from the `Set`, we immutably swap an element of both lists `a(i)<->b(i)`

It's clean but not efficient for long Lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional programming friendly approach:

```
def combine[T](xx: List[T], yy: List[T]): List[(List[T], List[T])] = (xx, yy) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => Nil
  case (x :: Nil, y :: Nil) => List(
    (List(x), List(y)),
    (List(y), List(x))
  )
  case (x :: xs, y :: ys) =>
    val results = combine(xs, ys)
    results.map { case (rx, ry) => (x :: rx, y :: ry) } ++
      results.map { case (rx, ry) => (y :: rx, x :: ry)}
  case _ =>
    sys.error("Input of non-matching sizes")
}
```

Unfortunately this is not tail recursive.

But it works:

```
val r = combine(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))
r.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(List(1, 2, 3),List(4, 5, 6))
(List(1, 2, 6),List(4, 5, 3))
(List(1, 5, 3),List(4, 2, 6))
(List(1, 5, 6),List(4, 2, 3))
(List(4, 2, 3),List(1, 5, 6))
(List(4, 2, 6),List(1, 5, 3))
(List(4, 5, 3),List(1, 2, 6))
(List(4, 5, 6),List(1, 2, 3))
```